# Why do I have to restart apache to properly refresh a Ruby on Rails view in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, refresh

I am trying to learn a bit of Ruby. I've installed Ruby on my Ubuntu machine and I am using apache. Everything works fine except to refresh a view I have to restart apache in the console and then hit ctrl-r, just pressing ctrl-r won't refresh the browser.

Apparently there's some caching going on, but does it have to be that way i.e. is it inherent to Ruby on Rails? I tried googling on this but it seems the only answer is to install some long-winded routine. For developing it seems like quite the tedious way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache's a perfectly good choice for development.

Just install Passenger (mod_rails)...and follow the instructions...

I set it up for each site so that /etc/hosts contains

```
127.0.0.1 myapp
```

I use Apache virtual hosts with an entry like so - in /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp
  DocumentRoot /path/to/myapp/public
  RailsEnv development
  RailsAllowModRewrite off
    <directory "/path/to/myapp/public">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable and restart

```
sudo a2ensite myapp
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

That way, there's no running script/server ... it's just always running in dev mode - just point your browser to http://myapp

Comment: Just what I wanted. I tried the Mongrel solution above with Apache as a front-end but this is a much nicer solution when you already have all this apache-stuff configured for your php-development and just want to get up and running.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use apache for development mode.  Use script/server and install the mongrel gem (sudo gem install mongrel).  Mongrel is faster than WEBrick and dumps the development log to the console in which it runs. It makes development decent.

Comment: Except in Vista.  Mongrel is slow as can be in Vista, use webrick instead.

Comment: Ruby/Rails is just slow in general on Windows.  It's honestly easier to develop in a Linux VM, especially if your app is sufficiently non-trivial.  I'm pretty sure that my current project doesn't even run on non-*nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is not a good choice for development in cases like Rails, because you will indeed need to restart the server every time you change code. Rails ships with its own development server that you can start by executing (IIRC) script/server. It's much more suitable for development, as it needn't be restarted after every little change.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't use apache for dev, mongrel is much easier, but setting the RailsEnv in passenger to development means that it doesn't do all the caching of views, classes etc, so you shouldn't have to restart.  Still think it's just easier to use mongrel or webrick for local dev though

Comment: i disagree.  it has been my experience that keeping the development environment as close to the deployment environment saves a lot of trouble when going live, especially with respect to additional modules and third party libraries.  We faced issues when we used Debian during development and then had to deploy on CentOS with SELinux enabled... keep development environment as close to deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Apache with Passenger (aka modrails) for development purposes, and it works fine here. Just make sure to use Rails in development mode by setting "RailsEnv development" in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache with mod_fcgid. I found that going

```
$ touch ${MYAPP}/tmp/restart.txt
```

every time I want the app reloaded works for me.