# I have to restart Apache every time I change my Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm running Rails 3 with Apache and Passenger. Ever since I switched from Mongrel to Passenger I find that I have to restart Apache every single time I change my code. Is this the intended behavior? Is the only way to avoid this problem to use Mongrel in development?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106996/why-do-i-have-to-restart-apache-to-properly-refresh-a-ruby-on-rails-view-in-the-b and the last part of http://blog.bsodmike.com/2010/06/05/howto-ruby-on-rails-with-apache-passenger-mod_rails-ubuntu-lucid-lynx-10-04/

Comment: Are you talking about production or development?

Comment: I don't know - I'm also having problems controlling whether I'm in production or development.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have to restart Apache even for model/view/controller code, it would seem as if you've set up Passenger to run your app in the production environment. You can fix this by appending `RailsEnv development` to your virtual host.

Some code will require you to restart the app--examples of this is anything in `config/initializers` and `vendor`.

There's a way to only restart the *app* (and not the entire server), which is simply `touch tmp/restart.txt`. This will update the timestamp of `tmp/restart.txt`, which will trigger Passenger to restart the app.

Additionally, you can do `touch tmp/always_restart.txt`. This will tell Passenger to restart the app on *every* page load. This can be useful if you're working on sections that require restarts (such as the examples mentioned above). To stop the automatic restarting, you'll have to delete the file, like this: `rm tmp/always_restart.txt`.

Comment: I missed `tmp/always_restart.txt`, much better than manually hitting `restart.txt` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use passenger by itself in development using the standalone mode.  From your project directory, type

```
passenger start
```