# Vagrant shared folder with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, nfs, shared-directory

I'm running rails on a nfs shared folder in a vagrant box. While the server (thin/webrick) is running I'm editing files in my host. But I have to keep stopping and restarting the application server to  see changes reflected in the webapp. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Maybe the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879604/i-have-to-restart-apache-every-time-i-change-my-rails-code

Comment: @MattCooper No I think it is a different beast. It is the sync process between the host and the vagrant VM.

Answer (score 2):

I go this issue on Vagrant box synchronising my folder with [NFS](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html).

I made a change in my application development configuration file (`config/environments/development.rb`), just adding this line `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false` and it works.

Ensure that you have this `config.cache_classes = false` as well, I had it by default when I setup rails application (using version 4.1.5), because where I found that workaround (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) says that `config.reload_classes_only_on_chage = false` is ignored if `config.cache_classes` is `true`

Another solution is use vagrant Rsync synchronise mechanism, which [is available from version 1.5](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-rsync.html) and have some benefits, but for me it doesn't work because I run out of space if I have to make a copy of my workspace on each virtual machine that I have.