# Rails 5 restart server every time controller or model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a vagrant box(ubuntu xenial) with my rails (5.0.0.1) development server and every time I change a model or a controller I need to restart the server.

I've tested with puma and webrick and the behavior is the same.

I do the development in my host machine which is a Windows 10 machine, vagrant creates a shared folder where I have my code.

I've checked if both the VM machine and my host are in sync in terms of time and they appear to be.
Another thing that I did was to check other threads here in SO regarding similar problems but I had no luck with the suggestions given.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a config issue. Is `cache_classes` set to false in your dev configs? Either in `app/config/environments/development.rb` or in `app/config/application.rb`

Comment: Yes my development.rb file has config.cache_classes = false

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've resolved the problem, I stumbled upon this post [Vagrant shared folder with rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051076/vagrant-shared-folder-with-rails-server?rq=1) which pointed me to the right direction.

Basicallly besides having:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

in the development.rb file it is also necessary to have:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36616931) might help as well 
`config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`