# Rails server needs restart every time I make changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Whenever I make changes in the controller or models I need to re-start the server. Please, kindly clarify me. Rails version 5.2.2

Comment: And what if you just reload a browser tab? Does it display changes? Do you use puma as rails server?

Answer (score 3):

Check your`config/environments/development.rb` file and see if you can find these lines:
`set config.cache_classes = false` and
`config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false`

You can refer to these answers:

[Rails Server needs restart every time I make changes? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270945/rails-server-needs-restart-every-time-i-make-changes-why)

[Vagrant shared folder with rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051076/vagrant-shared-folder-with-rails-server?rq=1)