# Caching with rails and apache behaves unexpectedly. Changes to the layout do not take effect until a apache restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, apache2

Good morning everyone,

in the last two days I have worked on my first Ruby on Rails website, which I would like to deploy on my virtual server.

I think that I have set up everything appropriately and I can request the website through my favourite browser (firefox). The website is mostly static, so it has a lot of static assets, which I need to precompile.

However, when I commit changes to the custom stylesheet and precompile it, the webserver (apache2 in combination with passenger) continues serving the old stylesheet/webpage, which is confusing me, since I thought that this should be prevented by the hashing mechanism, which rails uses for static assets.

Once I restart the apache server with 'service apache2 restart' and navigate by browser to the website, I get to see the new layout.

I suspect this to be an issue with the apache2 configuration, so here is my config of the virtual host (stripped from comments):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
RailsEnv production
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.1/ruby

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/file
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private/key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

<Directory />
       Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/project/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location /assets/>
    # Use of ETag is discouraged when Last-Modified is present                                                                                  
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    # RFC says only cache for 1 year                                                                                                            
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Does someone have a suggestion, where I can look for misconfiguration?
Thank you very much.

Further information:
Rails v5.2.1

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'passenger'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
    gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
    gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
    gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: did you check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106996/why-do-i-have-to-restart-apache-to-properly-refresh-a-ruby-on-rails-view-in-the

Comment: here are also some specific explanations: https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/apache-conf-for-rails-asset-pipeline/

Comment: Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106996/why-do-i-have-to-restart-apache-to-properly-refresh-a-ruby-on-rails-view-in-the regards using rails in development mode. In development mode, however, rails does serve static files itself and does not rely on the webserver serving precompiled static files.

Comment: I have implemented the suggestions from https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/apache-conf-for-rails-asset-pipeline/ (thanks for the link), but unfortunately it didn't help. The webpage is not under public/assets, anyway, so it would have been even more confusing if this solution had helped. Anyway, the arguments in the article are valid, so I have implemented the suggestions either way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running Rails in `production` mode, you'll need to restart the application server to pick up any changes to the code. In your case the application is served by the Passenger module inside Apache, so that explains why Apache needs to be restarted.

Comment: So every time I change my website just a little bit (eg I just change the layout of a site), I'll have to restart the apache server? Does rails hold the templates for the pages in its cache all the time instead of loading them when needed?

Comment: If you want changes in the filesystem to be reflected in the application immediately, you'll need to run it in development mode. For this, a simpler setup without Apache might be more appropriate, though. Why not just run `rails s`?

Comment: Cause I want the website to be as stable and secure as in production mode. When I develop changes, I don't mind doing this in development mode, but when I serve the page to my customers, I'd like it to be as stable and secure as possible and that is what production mode is made for. I'm just trying to understand why it is more stable or secure to keep the site templates in rails cache and not load it from the drive as needed. Is it good practice to restart the apache server each time one of your websites needs an update?

Comment: This has nothing to do with stability or security, but is mainly a performance aspect. Not having to monitor the filesystem and not needing to do auto-loading of unknown constants, the application server can load the code into memory at startup and that's it. Even though it is advisable to test the behaviour of the `production` environment before the actual deployment - for example on a staging system - you don't really gain anything by running it in `production` mode during development.